# How to type generic key in redux toolkit reducer? Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to reuse reducer but got an error while passing a string key

```
Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'Draft<T>'.
```

Any recommendations on how to type it? Or how can I reuse such functions differently

```
export type Type<T, K> = {
  builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<T>;
  thunk: AsyncThunk<AxiosResponse, K, Record<string, never>>;
  key: keyof T;
};

export const createPendingData = <T, K>(args: Type<T, K>) =>
  args.builder.addCase(args.thunk.pending, (state, action) => {
    if (state[args.key].status !== 'loading') {  // here the error
      state[args.key].requestId = action.meta.requestId; // here the error
      state[args.key].status = 'loading'; // here the error
    }
  });

export const extraReducers = (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<Schema>): void => {
      createPendingData<Schema, GetParams>({
        builder,
        thunk: getThunk,
        key: 'events',
      });
}

const initialState: BaseSchema = {
  requestId: '',
  status: 'idle',
  error: undefined,
  data: null,
};

export const state: Schema = {
  events: initialState,
};
```

Comment: export type Schema = {
  events: BaseSchema<{ result: Event[]; count: number } | null>;
};

Comment: Please provide the code of each type. Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using https://www.typescriptlang.org/play